# Read resources from multiple properties files in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have a spring project. I have created different properties files for different modules and these files are in their respective directories.

For example, in "resources" folder, I have "student" and "teacher" folders. In student folder, I have student_en.properties and in teacher folder, I have teacher_en.properties. Now how do I configure it in spring so that I can get locale specific properties from all files using "ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" or any other bean.

Right now, it is -

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames"
        value="classpath:messages" />
</bean>
```

Can I use regex or somehow include property files in all sub-directories of resources folder?

Answer (score 2):

Basenames accepts array as a parameter:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
      <util:list>
        <value>classpath:student/student</value>
        <value>classpath:teacher/teacher</value>
      </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: But is my sub-directory on classpath? Also, if I have to support 20 languages, then I would have to include 20*2=40 lines in <value> ?

Comment: Sorry,  I've fixed my answer. As I remember you should add directory,  because it works like package. You don't have to include language